# How to show popup message without having a context

Tags: android, notifications, toast, android-context, trial

We are developing a library that will be used both in `JVM` and `Android`. And now we need to implement trial period notification. In other platforms (.Net and Mac) showing a popup message box was enough. But so far I cannot find a way to do this for Android.

The problem is that to show some message (toast or AlertDialog), I need to have an actual context. But since our library doesn't contain UI elements and not related to UI in any way we are not asking a user to pass context when creating out components.

To be short:

- how can I show a Toast (AlertDialog, Notification)without having a context refference passed from user code.
- If I can't maybe someone have better solutions for implementing trial mode on Android and Java.

Comment: you can do nothing without a context. maybe provide an interface for notifications and let the user implement this interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you really can't show neither Toast nor AlertDialog without having a context. The most close variant is to provide some interface in your library that user should implement.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Your abstract factory will allow you to create dialogs and other notifications. Then you will have 2 concrete implementations that create the Android version or the JVM version of the notification.

Example:

```
/*
 * The abstract factory
 */
public abstract class NotificationFactory {
    /**
     * Pops a message up for the user.
     * 
     * @param msg
     */
    public abstract void newToast(String msg);

    // other notifications can go here
}

/**
 * Concrete Android notification factory
 * 
 */
public final class AndroidNotificationFactory extends NotificationFactory {

    private final Context context;

    public AndroidNotificationFactory(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void newToast(String msg) {
        // normal Android toast stuff using the context
    }

}

/**
 * Concrete JVM Notification factory
 * 
 */
public final class JvmNotificationFactory extends NotificationFactory {

    @Override
    public void newToast(String msg) {
        // JVM toast stuff
    }

}

/**
 * A singleton used for accessing the factory.
 * 
 */
public enum Library {
    Instance;

    private NotificationFactory notificationFactory;

    public NotificationFactory getNotificationFactory() {
        // nb: add synchronized if needed
        return notificationFactory;
    }

    public void setNotificationFactory(NotificationFactory notificationFactory) {
        // nb: add synchronized if needed
        this.notificationFactory = notificationFactory;
    }

    public void InitForAndroid(Context context) {
        setNotificationFactory(new AndroidNotificationFactory(context));
    }

    public void InitForJvm() {
        setNotificationFactory(new JvmNotificationFactory());
    }
}

public class ExampleUsage {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // init the library
        // Library.Instance.InitForAndroid(context); //or:
        Library.Instance.InitForJvm();

        // usage
        Library.Instance.getNotificationFactory().newToast("Test");

    }

}
```

With dialogs where you need to be able to call methods on after creation, you need to make an `IDialog` interface and concrete Android and JVM wrappers that implement that interface.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good example how to show notifications in platform-independent way. But the essence of question is how to force showing UI from my library. And it seems now, that I can't do this without reference to context.