# How to send a Toast or any user notification when no more context is available?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast, android-context

I have a `Fragment` in which I use an `AsyncTask` to send a tweet. I send the tweet in `doInBackground`, and when it's sent, `onPostExecute` is called and I'd like to show a `Toast` (or any notification) to the user.

The issue is that if the `Fragment` is paused (e.g. the user changed screens during the twitter request), no more context is available to call

```
Toast.makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

I'm aware of other similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189953/how-to-show-popup-message-without-having-a-context-android), but I couldn't find any answer...

... and keeping a local copy of the context seems very wrong.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think.. you can use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" to display a dialog when your app is not running too.

Comment: @Kettu:it's irrelevant

Comment: Use an `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask`, this way you can show `Toast` anytime.

Comment: Or, just extend the `Application` class and (since it's already a singleton) set it up with a singleton accessor. Toasting on the application context will work just fine. If you feel like something more fancy, you can always set up your own singleton which keeps a reference to the application context for toasting messags. [See also here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android/3827166#3827166).

Comment: @M-WaJeEh from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16766109/326849), it's dangerous.

Comment: @Jul Please consult rony l answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5420929/1112882

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18214792/1112882

Comment: @MH I'll use your solution, thanks. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per earlier comment:

You can extend the `Application` class and (since it's already a singleton) set it up with a singleton accessor. Toasting on the application context will work just fine. If you feel like something more fancy, you can always set up your own singleton which keeps a reference to the application context for toasting messages. [See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android/3827166#3827166).